# Is this the proper way I'm calculating RMS?

Tags: voltage, rms

I'm trying to calculate RMS value of the given graph. Am I doing this right?

[image: Calculations]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just compute the RMS values of each region separately. Imagine if the second region of the graph was zero instead of 200. By your method, the RMS of the total would be the same regardless of the length of time the second region was at zero - which is clearly wrong.

You need to compute the area of the entire graph (squared) first, then take the mean , then take the square root :-

$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{10}\Big(\int_0^51600x^2\,\mathrm dx + \int_5^{10}40000\,\mathrm dx\Big)}$$

Comment: I would normally agree with your general premise 100% - square, mean, squareroot but I think in this **particular** case it is much simpler. A linear ramp for 5 seconds and then a constant voltage for 35 that is always positive. Then repeat. In the first part (0 -5) this will give an average of 100V, in the second part (5-35) it is 200V. Averaging over the cycle gives (5*100)+(35*200)/40 = 187.5 Volts

Comment: @JImDearden - I'm not sure I understand. Where did the 35 seconds come from? The OP says the first region is 0 to 5s and the second from 5 to 10s. In any case you appear to have calculated an average voltage which is only the same as RMS voltage for he second (constant) region, but not for the ramp. The answer to the original question is 163.3 Vrms.

Comment: My mistake - it was the hand written 10, it looked like 40 to my old eyes and yes you are quite right about the ramp as well so +1 from me